# couldn't install pacakges dur to os error

Tags: installation, package, operating-system

C:\Users\CHERRY>pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\python311\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Failed to parse: http://your.proxy.server:port

i tried upgrading pip but didnt work give a solution that would help